# Tkinter master change dimension while trying to plot a pie chart

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to draw  an circle inside my tkinter GUI using below function. I am calling this function after every 5 seconds.

```
def make_pie(x):
value = [x,100-x]
if value[0]>=75:
colors = ['#00FF00','#efefef']
elif value[0]<75 and value[0]>50:
colors = ['#FFFF00','#efefef']
else:
colors = ['#FF0000','#efefef']
# Pie Chart
plt.pie(value, colors=colors, pctdistance=0.85)
#autopct='%1.1f%%'
# draw circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.6, fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
          
# Adding Circle in Pie chart
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
plt.savefig('pie.png')

make_pie(x)
```

But the above function is changing my dimension of my tkinter master frame. How do I fix that?

I tried to look into the functions called by plt, if it changing my master frame.

Comment: First your posted code has indentation issue.  Second there is no tkinter related code.  So it is better to provide a [mre].